# Symfony not found page

Tags: symfony4

How to set a universal nof found page in symfony 4.1? The next code

```
/**
 * @Route("/{notfoundurl}", name="path_notfound")
 */
public function notFound() {
    return $this->render('templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig', []);
}
```

resist using other urls like /login

```
http://localhost:8000/login
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to override twig template of error page. See the doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

If you are in dev mode, you have to see this doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development